# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Q'

Tags: python

So this situation I am making is: "The code will ask for integer value and evaluate it (checks if it’s positive or negative). The code must keep asking for the next number. You can press Q to exit."

```
while True:
     
     userValue = int(input('Please enter a number: '))

     if userValue < 0:                        
          print("This is a Negative Number")

     if userValue > 0:
          print("This is a Positive Number")

     if str(userValue) == 'Q':
          print("EXIT")
```

But I keep getting the error "**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Q'**"
I can't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: You are inputting "Q" which cannot be converted to an integer in the first line.

Comment: You should add another case for when the input is not convert-able to a number, something like a try-except block.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you are converting the input directly to int. This gives a error because obviously `"Q"` is not a number. Instead, I would recommend that you first use the string to check if the user typed `"Q"` and then convert to a integer to check for the number:

```
userValue = input('Please enter a number: ')
if str(userValue) == 'Q':
     print("EXIT")
else:
    userValue = int(userValue)
    if userValue < 0:                        
        print("This is a Negative Number")

    if userValue > 0:
        print("This is a Positive Number")
```

To make it loop, you can put the whole thing in a `while(True)` loop and break in the first if case.

Answer (score 0):

Test for `Q` before, not after, converting to `int`. I also suggest to use snake case for most variable names, and add some exception handling:

```
while True:
    user_value = input('Please enter an integer number, or Q to quit: ')
    
    if user_value == 'Q':
        print("EXIT")
        exit(0)

    try:
        user_value = int(user_value)
    except:
        print(f"'{user_value}' is not allowed.")
        exit(2)
        
    if user_value < 0:                        
        print("This is a negative number") 
    elif user_value > 0:
        print("This is a positive number")
    else:
        print("Zero")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are inputting 'Q' into the program it cannot be converted using `int()` function present in line 1. When you try to convert a character to an integer value that is when you get `ValueError`.

This could be a possible solution

```
userValue = input('Please enter a number: ')
try:
    value = int(userValue)
    if value < 0:                        
        print("This is a Negative Number")
    if value > 0:
        print("This is a Positive Number")

except ValueError:
    if userValue == 'Q':
        print("EXIT")
```